# Drop down nav menu off when decreasing browser size

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, nav

I'm working at making a responsive site and on this site I have a drop down menu. When I bring the size down to 900px I keep the menu, but it gets pressed all the way to the left side of my browser. I gave it a little left padding just so it would be off the wall till it hits 600px at which point it goes into a list-block view and I hide drop down box. Basically I need to find a way to keep the drop down menu between 600px and 900px so that it will still show up under the respective places they're supposed to. Including [a screen shot to show what's happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C7iN.jpg)

Edit: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhEk4/)

And now my code

HTML5

```
<nav>
    <nav class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="appliances.html">Appliances</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Electronics/index.html">Electronics</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Electronics/computers.html">Computers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Electronics/game_systems.html">Game Systems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Electronics/televisions.html">Televisions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Furniture/index.html">Furniture</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Furniture/bedroom.html">Bedroom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Furniture/dining_room.html">Dining Room</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Furniture/living_room.html">Living Room</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="location.html">Location</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</nav>
```

CSS3

```
/*Default CSS*/
.main-header nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.main-header nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.main-header nav ul {
    background: #efefef;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

.main-header nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.main-header nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

.main-header nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
}

.main-header nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.main-header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-header nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

.main-header nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}

.main-header nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-header nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

    /*Between 600px and 900px*/

.main-header nav ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 10%;
}

.main-header nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
```

As you can see I haven't messed with a lot of it, I think the work I need should be with just these two lines. If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to look into media query, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I'm using the media tag, I just didn't include it in my code because I didn't think it was important. I said the dimensions I'm working on in between 600px and 900px so I thought it would stand to reason that I was working within that range.

Comment: Tried to put your code in a fiddle, it does not work. Either provide more code or give a link to the problematic page

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhEk4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute positioned dropdown needs to be inside of a relative positioned container

```
.main-header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UhEk4/2/

Obviously there are more work to be done to adjust the positions but you should be able to take it from here